# how to edit css and html for github pages, jekyll + minima theme

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I've re-read the instructions several times and searched these forums for answers; apologies if I'm missing something really obvious.

I can't get CSS or HTML templates to work on my GitHub pages site. I get the following error for the template:

```
The page build failed for the `master` branch with the following error:

A file was included in `/_layouts/home.html` that is a symlink or does not exist in your `_includes` directory. For more information, see https://help.github.com/en/articles/page-build-failed-file-is-a-symlink.
```

The CSS I've tried, just turning the background black, also doesn't seem to work.

The test site is located here: https://prismspecs.github.io/

repo: https://github.com/prismspecs/prismspecs.github.io/

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because of a mismatch between your `_layouts/home.html` and theme.
The layout is asking for three includes which do not exist in your repository nor inside the [`jekyll-theme-minimal`](https://github.com/pages-themes/minimal).

The solution is to either remove the custom layout or add the three includes to your repo.